# numpy: find first index of value in each row of 2D array

Tags: numpy

How can I find the first index of a value in each row of a 2D array, using vectorized numpy functions?

For example, given

```
I = numpy.array([1,1,1]
M = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]])
```

The output should be:

```
array([0, 2, 1])
```

I can do it with a list comprehension like this:

```
[ numpy.where(M[i] == I[i])[0][0] for i in range(0, len(I)) ]
```

What would the numpy equivalent be?

Comment: Could you post an example of input data and the output you expect? For example, `M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` and `I = np.array([5,6,1])`. Thanks

Comment: Added example input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility of exploiting vectorization is as follows

```
coords = ((I[:, np.newaxis] == M) * np.arange(M.shape[1], 0, -1)[np.newaxis, :]).argmax(1)
any = (I[:, np.newaxis] == M).any(1)
coords = coords[any]
```

It disambiguates between several occurrences of the value of interest in the same line by multiplying a decreasing counter to each line, making the first occurence have the highest value. If a given line does not contain the indicated value, then it is removed from `coords`.  The remaining lines (in which the corresponding value was found) are indexed by `any`

Answer (score 1):

I think these might do it, step by step:

```
In [52]:

I = np.array([1,1,1])
#M = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]])
M = np.array([[4,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,2]])
In [53]:

I1=I.reshape((-1,1))
In [54]:

M1=np.hstack((M, I1))
In [55]:

np.apply_along_axis(np.argmax, 1, (M1-I1)==0)
Out[55]:
array([3, 3, 3])
```

If the number is not found in `M`, the resulting index is `M.shape[1]`. Since the result is an `array` of `int`, put a `nan` in those cells is not an option. But we may consider put  `-1` for those cases, if the result is `result`:

```
result[result==(M.shape[1])]=-1
```